# I want to add a new value to the list on pressing send button and display the list on the screen in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to populate the list with the widgets of the messages. The message will be taken from the text of TextFieldController that the user will enter. On pressing send button, I want the text to be added into the list and the list will be displayed in the ListView on the screen.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _query = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    List<MessageBubble> _messages = []; //Empty List
    TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(


Body of the app is starting from here

        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(_query.height * 0.03),
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _query.height * 0.05),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                  ..._messages //List of messages
                ],
              ),
            ),








This is the TextField with send button. I want the send button to add the controller text to the list that is being displayed on the screen


            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: _query.width * 0.04),
                  child: Container(
                    width: _query.width * 0.8,
                    height: 75,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _messageController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      cursorColor: Color.fromRGBO(168, 168, 168, 1),
                      cursorHeight: 20.0,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Enter your message',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(166, 166, 166, 1)),
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(166, 166, 166, 1))),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(166, 166, 166, 1))),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(166, 166, 166, 1))),
                          hoverColor: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: _query.height * 0.015,
                  ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    customBorder: CircleBorder(),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        print(_messages);
                        _messages.add(MessageBubble(
                          message: _messageController.text,
                          sender: 'Mubashir',
                        ));
                        _messageController.clear();
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(_query.width * 0.04),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.send,
                        size: _query.width * 0.07,
                        color: AppColors().liteColorWithOpacity(1.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the MessageBubble Class in which I'm receiving the userName and message from TextFieldController and returning the widget.

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final String sender;
  final bool isMe;

  MessageBubble({this.message, this.sender, this.isMe = true});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment:
          isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            print('Selected');
          },
          child: Material(
            color: AppColors().liteColorWithOpacity(1.0),
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0))
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0)),
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: AppColors().white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mubashir, Welcome to StackOverflow. You code seem to be correct. Can you tell us what problem you're facing. Are your messages not added to the list? Can you check if your widget is StatefulWidget?

Comment: Yes the widget is StatefulWidget but the messages are not being added to the list on pressing send. When I print the list on the console, it is being printed as an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The list is in the build method which would result in reinitializing the list every time the widget rebuilds.

Move it to the class level.

```dart
class SomeWidget {
  final List<MessageBubble> _messages = []; //Empty List

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Thanks a lot